# Other use for a Hibernate Mapping file

Tags: hibernate, erd

I am trying to define db dependency for a web based application, and was thinking that perhaps the hibernate mappings used in the application might be importable into some sort of tool to produce a visual ERD diagram.  Has anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 3):

The Hibernate Tools plugin for Eclipse allows to [visualize the Data Model](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/) with the "Mapping Diagram":

[image]
<sub>(source: [relation.to](http://relation.to/service/File/2987))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [visual nhibernate](http://www.slyce.com/) that does something like this. It's goal isn't to create ERD's but it does show that it's possible